# What is the command to "go to current statement" in IDA debugger?

Tags: ida, windows, debuggers

I'm trying to learn how to use the IDA pro debugger (having used Visual Studio's C++ debugger for years) and I'm struggling to find how to switch the code/asm view back to the current instruction that debugger broke on?

Similar to the "Show next statement" button in Visual Studio:

[image]

PS. Here's my situation. Say, I broke on some instruction and then using IDA's "graph view" navigated away from that instruction. How do I go back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can navigate back to the previous position simply by pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd>. If you want to back to the current IP address, just press the right mouse button a select <kbd>Jump to IP</kbd>

.
[image: Jump To IP]

Alternatively you can press <kbd>G</kbd> and set `EIP` as address.

Comment: Oops. Thanks. I should've thought about it myself.

Comment: As a side note... do they rename it to "Jump to RIP" for x64 process :)

Comment: There will come a time when people read help before posting to stackexchange.

Comment: @VitalyOsipov: You know that it would take you less time to answer my question then to post what you did above?

Comment: @c00000fd give a man a fish and you feed him for a day, teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime

Comment: @VitalyOsipov: You really have nothing else to do, do you?